# Create / Edit / Retrieve DB file with GDAA (Google Drive Api for Android)

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, database-backups, google-drive-android-api

skilled friends.

Could you someone help me with my problem, please? I'm trying to use GDAA (Google Drive API for Android = https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder) for backup and restore my DB file. Not REST API.
I tried use their demo classes from here: https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/, but no positive result.

I suceed with authentication and with save my DB file into App Folder in Google Drive, but I can not edit or retrieve this file. I only still create new and new files. Could you help me, please?

I call this Edit activity:

```
public class EditContentsActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

private static final String TAG = "EditContentsActivity";

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);

    final ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CreateFileInAppFolderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }

            DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), result.getDriveId());
            new EditContentsAsyncTask(EditContentsActivity.this).execute(file);
        }
    };
    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FILE_ID)
            .setResultCallback(idCallback);
}

public class EditContentsAsyncTask extends ApiClientAsyncTask<DriveFile, Void, Boolean> {

    public EditContentsAsyncTask(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackgroundConnected(DriveFile... args) {
        DriveFile file = args[0];
        try {
            DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = file.open(
                    getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null).await();
            if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                return false;
            }
            DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
            OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();

            String dbpath = "/data/" + "com.myapp" + "/databases/" + DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME;
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory() + dbpath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status =
                    driveContents.commit(getGoogleApiClient(), null).await();

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            fis.close();

            return status.getStatus().isSuccess();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException while appending to the output stream", e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (!result) {
            showMessage("Error while editing contents");
            return;
        }
        showMessage("Successfully edited contents");
    }
}
```

If I get "!result.getStatus().isSuccess()" I want to call Create Activity:

```
public class CreateFileInAppFolderActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    // create new contents resource
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
                    return;
                }

                String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType("db");
                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle(EXISTING_FILE_ID)
                        .setMimeType(mimeType)
                        .build();
                OutputStream os  = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
               try {
                    String dbpath = "/data/" + "com.myapp" + "/databases/" + DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME;
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory() + dbpath);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                   Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                           .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getDriveContents())
                           .setResultCallback(fileCallback);

                   os.flush();
                   os.close();
                   fis.close();

                   throw new IOException("");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("IOExceptions=", e.toString());
                   Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(getGoogleApiClient()).delete(getGoogleApiClient());
                }

            }
        };

final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
                    return;
                }
                showMessage("Created a file in App Folder: "
                        + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
            }
        };
```

All extend this Base Demo Activity:

```
public abstract class BaseDemoActivity extends Activity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "BaseDriveActivity";

/**
 * DriveId of an existing folder to be used as a parent folder in
 * folder operations samples.
 */
public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "0B2EEtIjPUdX6MERsWlYxN3J6RU0";

/**
 * DriveId of an existing file to be used in file operation samples..
 */
public static final String EXISTING_FILE_ID = "0ByfSjdPVs9MZTHBmMVdSeWxaNTg";

/**
 * Extra for account name.
 */
protected static final String EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME = "account_name";

/**
 * Request code for auto Google Play Services error resolution.
 */
protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;

/**
 * Next available request code.
 */
protected static final int NEXT_AVAILABLE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

/**
 * Google API client.
 */
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/**
 * Called when activity gets visible. A connection to Drive services need to
 * be initiated as soon as the activity is visible. Registers
 * {@code ConnectionCallbacks} and {@code OnConnectionFailedListener} on the
 * activities itself.
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

/**
 * Handles resolution callbacks.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

/**
 * Called when activity gets invisible. Connection to Drive service needs to
 * be disconnected as soon as an activity is invisible.
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

/**
 * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is connected.
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
}

/**
 * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is disconnected.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}

/**
 * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is trying to connect but failed.
 * Handle {@code result.getResolution()} if there is a resolution is
 * available.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows a toast message.
 */
public void showMessage(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

/**
 * Getter for the {@code GoogleApiClient}.
 */
public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
  return mGoogleApiClient;
}
```

Retrieve Activity:

```
public class RetrieveContentsActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

private static final String TAG = "RetrieveContentsActivity";

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FILE_ID)
            .setResultCallback(idCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
        new RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask(
                RetrieveContentsActivity.this).execute(result.getDriveId());
    }
};

final private class RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask
        extends ApiClientAsyncTask<DriveId, Boolean, String> {

    public RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackgroundConnected(DriveId... params) {
        String contents = null;
        DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), params[0]);
        DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult =
                file.open(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();
        if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            return null;
        }
        DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(driveContents.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            contents = builder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException while reading from the stream", e);
        }

        driveContents.discard(getGoogleApiClient());
        return contents;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result == null) {
            showMessage("Error while reading from the file");
            return;
        }
        showMessage("File contents: " + result);
    }
}
```

And there is Authentication code:

```
public abstract class ApiClientAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
    extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

private GoogleApiClient mClient;

public ApiClientAsyncTask(Context context) {
    GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE);
    mClient = builder.build();
}

@Override
protected final Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
    Log.d("TAG", "in background");
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    mClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(new ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    mClient.registerConnectionFailedListener(new OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    mClient.connect();
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!mClient.isConnected()) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return doInBackgroundConnected(params);
    } finally {
        mClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Override this method to perform a computation on a background thread, while the client is
 * connected.
 */
protected abstract Result doInBackgroundConnected(Params... params);

/**
 * Gets the GoogleApliClient owned by this async task.
 */
protected GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
    return mClient;
}
```

Do you know the right approach with this demo, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have time to dig through all of the code above, but I can (at least) give you some general pointers.

First, the demos you mention do work, I've tested it and have it running. But since the demos cover just about any scenario, it is difficult to trace your possible error.

Now, the pointers:

1. When you create a file, you get back a DriveId.
2. You use that DriveId to retrieve the file
3. The content of the file is a binary byte array or stream

I've put together a basic CRUD wrapper for the GDAA, you can find it [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo).

In the [GDAA.java](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/gdaademo/GDAA.java) class, you'll find '*createFile()*' method. I think you have to give it the '*result.getDriveFile().getDriveId()*' that you received in your '*fileCallback*' above (as a parent). The content is passed in as a standard java.io.File

That method returns DriveId (in String form so I can easily cache it) and you can pass that DriveId to the 'read()' method that will give you a byte array (stream) back. Dump it to a java.io.File and you're done (don't forget to run it off-UI thread, they are blocking methods).

I would recommend to test it first using Drive's root (not app folder), so you can actually see the file in drive.google.com

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply with the instructions. Your demo looks great, it could help me to solve my problem. But I'm unexpectedly indisposed for some time, so I will try it as soon as possible and let you know. :-)

Comment: If you use it, test in in the "root" first, I have never played with the app folder, just guessing that the only difference will be the parent folder id ('appfolder DriveId' vs 'standard folder DriveId').

Comment: You are right. There is only need to add `.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)` to `mGAC` in boolean method `init()`. Then set folder `DriveFolder df = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGAC);` and use it.

Thank you again. First I tried classic folder and after that AppFolder. Both cases work, there is only little "delay" (cache in Google Services), because when I trash/delete folder and file completelly, code says that item still exists for some time.