# Sync Room Database in Google Drive?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to sync room database with google drive and I have followed this document https://medium.com/glucosio-project/backup-restore-a-realm-database-on-google-drive-with-drive-api-c238515a5975 but I can't sync database in the drive.

I also tried to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297966/8143436 this answer and also,try to sync database like below :

I have tried below:

```
  private fun singIn() {
    val requiredScopes = HashSet<Scope>(2)

    requiredScopes.add(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    val signInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity!!)

    if (signInAccount != null && signInAccount.grantedScopes.containsAll(requiredScopes)) {
        initializeDriveClient(signInAccount)
    } else {
        val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .build()

        val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity!!, signInOptions)
        startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.signInIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
    }
}

private fun initializeDriveClient(signInAccount: GoogleSignInAccount) {
    driveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(activity!!, signInAccount)
    driveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(activity!!, signInAccount)
    onDriveClientReady()
}

   private fun onDriveClientReady() {

    getRootFolder()
  }

private fun getRootFolder() {
    /* Get the app folder */
    val appFolderTask = driveResourceClient!!.rootFolder

    appFolderTask.addOnSuccessListener {

        baseFolder = it
        checkForBackUp()
    }
    appFolderTask.addOnFailureListener {

    }

}

private fun checkForBackUp() {
    val query = Query.Builder()
        .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, BACK_UP))
        .build()


    val queryTask = baseFolder?.let { driveResourceClient?.queryChildren(it, query) }
    queryTask!!.addOnSuccessListener(activity!!, object : OnSuccessListener<MetadataBuffer> {
        override fun onSuccess(metadataBuffer: MetadataBuffer?) {
            if (metadataBuffer?.count == 0) {
                Log.d("TTTT", "File $BACK_UP not found\n")

                /* Make file backup */
                backUpDatabase()
            } else {
                Log.d("TTTT", metadataBuffer?.count.toString() + " Instances of file " + BACK_UP + " found\n")
                val metadata = metadataBuffer?.get(metadataBuffer.count - 1)
                restoreBackUp(metadata?.driveId!!.asDriveFile())
            }
        }


    })
}

  private fun restoreBackUp(asDriveFile: DriveFile?) {
 //        if (!dbShm.exists()) {
 //            Log.d("Hello", "Local database not found?!\\n") 
//            return
 //        }
    val dbFileOld = activity!!.getDatabasePath("my_db")


    /* Check of dbFileExists on device, delete if it does because it needs to be completely over written */
    if (dbFileOld.exists()) {
        dbFileOld.delete()
    }


    val dbFileNew = activity!!.getDatabasePath("my_db")

    val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(dbFileNew)
    val openFileTask = driveResourceClient?.openFile(asDriveFile!!, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    openFileTask?.continueWith { p0 ->
        val backupContents = p0.result
        val inputStream = backupContents!!.inputStream
        Log.d("TTTT", "Attempting to restore from database\n")
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var c: Int = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.size)
        while (c != -1 && c > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, c)
            c = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.size)
        }
        fileOutputStream.flush()
        fileOutputStream.close()
        fileOutputStream.flush()
        fileOutputStream.close()
        Log.d("TTTT", "Database restored\n")

        driveResourceClient!!.discardContents(backupContents)
    }?.addOnFailureListener {
        Log.d("TTTT", "Could not read file contents\\n")
    }


}

private fun backUpDatabase() {
    val db = activity!!.getDatabasePath("my_db")


    if (!db.exists()) {
        Log.d("TTTT", "Local database not found?!\\n")
        return
    }

    val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(db)
    val createContentsTask = driveResourceClient?.createContents()
    Log.d("TTTT", "Creating a back-up of the Database File\n")
    Tasks.whenAll(createContentsTask).continueWithTask {
        val contents = createContentsTask?.result
        val outputStream = contents?.outputStream
        Log.d("TTTT", "Attempting to write\\n")
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)


        var c: Int = fileInputStream.read(buffer)

        while (c != -1) {
            outputStream?.write(buffer, 0, c)
            c = fileInputStream.read(buffer)
        }


        outputStream!!.flush()
        outputStream.close()
        fileInputStream.close()
        Log.d("TTTT", "Database written\\n")
        val changeSet = MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
            .setTitle(BACK_UP)
            .setMimeType("application/x-sqlite3")
            .setStarred(false)
            .build()
        driveResourceClient!!.createFile(baseFolder!!, changeSet, contents)
    }.addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.d("TTTT", "Back up file created\n")
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Log.d("TTTT", "Could not create back up file\n")
    }

}
```

is this possible to sync the room database in google drive?

Comment: the database is just a file. You just need to sync the file. What have you tried, and what exactly was the problem there?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have tried to store a simple database file but when I import file from a drive that file corrupted

Comment: you probably save it or store it incorrectly then

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko if you have any example how to do? then let me know

Comment: you can find a tone of examples using search. If you want help - please post what exactly you tried

Comment: I have many searches but I can not find any solution and I have spent more than 2 days then I will ask a question here

Comment: If you have any reference link or any document let me know..it would be helpful for me

Comment: Please read carefully: This is not a place to ask someone to search for you. You have tried something, then it didn't work. Now please post what exactly you have tried, describe what did not work, and we will try  to help. If you have tried multiple things - post any of them. But you absolutely have to show what you have tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195330/discussion-between-mahesh-vayak-and-vladyslav-matviienko).

Comment: @MaheshVayak, did you find a solution?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Such a typical stack overflow attitude. I hope one day this site changes for the better.